# Using PWM in a Windows 10 App with the Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: gpio, led, pwm, windows-iot

I am a newbie an I have succesfully use a RBG Led, and I emulated PWM by code but it is too slow (and in somehow the timer autostops),

Then I watched that the standard libraries support GPIO.PWM but does the Windows10 IoT support native GPIO PWM output?, there is no clue inside the GpioPin class, neither GpioController, Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current documentation appears to be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.gpio.aspx

As you can see there are only read and write methods to affect the state.

I expect the best you can do is to launch a separate thread and implement software timed PWM.

Comment: I hope in the final release this get implemented, or might be Raspberry makes a UWP api to use that, but loses the flair. I will take a look to the Build videos to know if there is something about that. thanks anyway

Comment: Anyway just to know, I did a timer using System.Threading.Timer in order to make it independent, and setting the values low and high, have you seen c# code like that?

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello sorry, I'm not familiar with C#.  On the Pi some of the more interesting stuff uses the SOC's hardware peripherals (PWM/PCM/DMA).  I expect in time that someone will write Window's IoT drivers for that hardware (probably not Microsoft though).

Comment: Actually the Pi seems to be following along with things that are in Microframeworks (which became IoT), and they indeed include PWM. So if it is not here now, it probably will be ... someday. When is always a gamble.

Comment: @Spiked3 Shows my ignorance, I've never heard of microframeworks.  I had a quick look through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee435793.aspx but didn't spot the PWM stuff.

Comment: They are probably calling IoT now. A line of code is "PWM servo = new PWM(PWMChannels.PWM_PIN_D5, 20000, 1500, PWM.ScaleFactor.Microseconds, false);"  See an old post of mine http://www.spiked3.com/netduino-plus-2-3-4-1-sample-code  Look in program.cs in the zip.

Comment: Yeah, they have it buried; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.spot.hardware.pwm(v=vs.102).aspx